# Background Thread and Join will make the thread as foreground thread

Tags: multithreading

If I have a background thread and having Join to wait for completing background thread then does it mean it will work like same as foreground thread, if not then what is the difference.

```
Thread worker = new Thread(() => Console.ReadLine());
            worker.IsBackground = true ;
            worker.Start();  
            worker.Join();
```

Can I say above code will work like a foreground thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what you mean by "work like a foreground thread". The thread is still separate from the main thread - for example it can't do GUI work in a Forms app - but your main thread will pause at Join until the background thread completes.